# FBX SDK - Get the FbxNode from an ENodeId of a Character

Tags: python, c++, autodesk, fbx, motionbuilder

Is it possible to get the associated `FbxNode` from the enum ENodeId ?
for example if i want to get the FbxNode from the `Character::eLeftHand`

I tried to use `Character::GetCharacterLink(ENodeId, FbxCharacterLink)`
then extracting the FbxNode from `FbxCharacterLink` simply by calling `FbxCharacterLink::mNode`

However this function returns for most ENodeIds False, so no `FbxCharacterLink` is created.

```
character = myScene.GetCharacter(0)
lefthand = character.eLeftHand
lefthand_node = FbxCharacterLink()
character.GetCharacterLink(lefthand, lefthand_node) # False
lefthand_node = lefthand_node.mNode
```

when I was scripting inside Motionbuilder using Python and `Pyfbxsdk`, it was very easy, no matter how the skeleton objects are named, I can get the `FBXObject` of it

```
m = character.GetModel(self.BodyNodeObject[o])
```

and `BodyNodeObject` is generated with

```
def BodyNodes(self):
    for i in dir(FBBodyNodeId):
        if i[0] == 'k':
            try:
                self.BodyNodeObject[BodyNodesId[i]] = getattr(FBBodyNodeId, i)
            except:
                pass
```

`BodyNodesId` is simply a dictionary

```
BodyNodesId = OrderedDict({
        'kFBChestNodeId':'Spine1',
        'kFBHeadNodeId':'Head',
        'kFBHipsNodeId':'Hips',
        'kFBLeftAnkleNodeId':'LeftFoot',
        'kFBLeftCollarNodeId':'LeftShoulder',
        'kFBLeftElbowNodeId':'LeftForeArm',
        ...
})
```

Comment: Is this a c++ or python question? The FBX SDK for c++ states GetCharacterLink(..) but also FindCharacterLink(..) with quite a different set of arguments. See http://docs.autodesk.com/FBX/2014/ENU/FBX-SDK-Documentation/index.html?url=cpp_ref/class_fbx_node.html,topicNumber=cpp_ref_class_fbx_node_html6b73528d-77ae-4781-b04c-da4af82b4a08 . You can extract the node names simply by descending down the hierarchy recursively and calling GetName() at every child FBXNode. But I'm not sure if this would solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this worked for me

```
from fbx import *

for i in range(myscene.GetCharacterCount()):
    character = myscene.GetCharacter(i)
    node = character.eHips
    link = FbxCharacterLink()
    while (character.GetCharacterLink(node, link)):
        print node, link.mNode.GetName()
        node = character.ENodeId(int(node+1))
```